# Split image into parts

Tags: image, graphics, imagemagick, gimp

Is there anything in imagemagick or gimp or other linux compatible tool what can automatically detect individual objects on image and either return some location of object or store each object as separate image?

I have image like [this one](http://st.depositphotos.com/1064024/545/i/450/depositphotos_5451352-Meat-collection.jpg):

[image]

For other images where objects are located on a grid, I have successfully used `crop` operator in imagemagick, e.g. for 3x3 grid:

```
convert -crop 3x3@ in-image.jpg  out-image-%d.jpg
```

I cannot use `crop` when there is no rectangular grid, but I thought that white color should be enough for objects separation.

Comment: I would write this as comment but I can't do it yet. So you had a look to fiji, it has a lot of tools and maybe you can plug something together. Also makros are possible so you can automize the procedure.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that the background pixels will always be white?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, in this case, all background pixels are white.

Comment: Interesting problem. These references may be of help... https://code.google.com/p/cvblob/  and http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10889&hilit=blob+count

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is asking for a recommendation for a tool to solve your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done with ImageMagick in multiple steps. The orignal image is named meat.jpg:

```
convert meat.jpg -threshold 98% -morphology Dilate Octagon meat_0.png
```

[image: meat_0.png]

```
convert meat_0.png text: | grep -m 1 black
```

This gives you a pixel location in the area of the first part of meat:

```
131,11: (  0,  0,  0)  #000000  black
```

We'll use this to color the first piece in red, separate the red channel and then create and apply the mask for the first piece:

```
 convert meat_0.png -fill red -bordercolor white \
         -draw 'color 131,11 filltoborder' meat_1_red.png
 convert meat_1_red.png -channel R -separate meat_1.png
 convert meat_1_red.png meat_1.png -compose subtract \
         -threshold 50% -composite -morphology Dilate Octagon \
         -negate meat_1_mask.png
 convert meat_1_mask.png meat.jpg -compose Screen -composite \
         -trim meat_1.jpg
```

The resulting meat_1.jpg is already trimmed. You can then proceed the same way with meat_1.png in stead of meat_0.png, generating meat_2.png as the basis for successive iterations on the fly. Maybe this can be further simplified and wrapped in a shell script.

[image: meat_1.jpg]

Answer (score 15):

I would tackle this with a *"Connected Components Analysis"*, or *"Image Segmentation"* approach, like this...

First, split the input image into components, specifying a minimum size (in order to remove smaller lumps) and allowing for 8-connectivity (i.e. the 8 neighbouring pixels N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW are considered neighbours) rather than 4-connectivity - which only considers N, E, S and W pixels connected.

```
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2VEJ.jpg -threshold 98% \
    -morphology dilate octagon                            \
    -define connected-components:area-threshold=800       \
    -define connected-components:verbose=true             \
    -connected-components 8 -auto-level PNG8:lumps.png
```

which gives this output:

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 450x450+0+0 219.2,222.0 93240 srgb(255,255,255)
  14: 127x98+111+158 173.0,209.4 9295 srgb(0,0,0)
  29: 105x91+331+303 384.1,346.9 6205 srgb(0,0,0)
  8: 99x75+340+85 388.9,124.6 5817 srgb(1,1,1)
  15: 110x69+330+168 385.4,204.9 5640 srgb(1,1,1)
  3: 114x62+212+12 270.0,42.4 5021 srgb(0,0,0)
  4: 103x63+335+12 388.9,44.9 4783 srgb(0,0,0)
  11: 99x61+13+134 61.5,159.1 4181 srgb(0,0,0)
  37: 128x52+313+388 375.1,418.4 4058 srgb(0,0,0)
  24: 95x62+24+256 69.6,285.7 4017 srgb(0,0,0)
  2: 91x68+15+12 62.0,44.4 3965 srgb(0,0,0)
  38: 91x50+10+391 55.1,417.0 3884 srgb(0,0,0)
  12: 83x64+249+134 288.3,168.4 3761 srgb(0,0,0)
  19: 119x62+320+240 385.4,268.4 3695 srgb(9,9,9)
  25: 93x63+128+268 176.1,302.1 3612 srgb(0,0,0)
  39: 96x49+111+391 158.1,416.0 3610 srgb(0,0,0)
  31: 104x59+117+333 172.9,360.1 3493 srgb(0,0,0)
  33: 88x55+238+335 279.3,364.5 3440 srgb(0,0,0)
  26: 121x54+230+271 287.6,294.0 3431 srgb(8,8,8)
  1: 98x61+109+11 159.7,40.0 3355 srgb(0,0,0)
  40: 88x42+218+399 262.3,419.7 3321 srgb(0,0,0)
  6: 87x61+115+70 157.9,100.1 3263 srgb(0,0,0)
  30: 97x57+14+327 57.3,357.2 3237 srgb(55,55,55)
  17: 84x57+13+207 53.1,232.2 2995 srgb(0,0,0)
  5: 107x58+10+68 58.9,97.5 2988 srgb(0,0,0)
  18: 77x60+237+212 273.0,243.0 2862 srgb(0,0,0)
  7: 87x49+249+78 291.8,99.3 2703 srgb(9,9,9)
  10: 82x51+178+109 222.8,133.9 2628 srgb(0,0,0)
```

Each line corresponds to a separate component, or segment, and shows the widths and heights of the bounding boxes for each component, and their offsets from the top-left corner. You can parse that easily enough with `awk` and draw the indicated red boxes onto the image to give this:

[image]

The output image is called `lumps.png` and it looks like this:

[image]

and you can see that each component (piece of meat) has a different grey level associated with it. You can also analyse `lumps.png`, and extract a separate mask for each piece of meat, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Extract every grey level, and montage together all that are not entirely black
rm mask_*png 2> /dev/null
mask=0
for v in {1..255}; do
   ((l=v*255))
   ((h=l+255))
   mean=$(convert lumps.png -black-threshold "$l" -white-threshold "$h" -fill black -opaque white -threshold 1 -verbose info: | grep -c "mean: 0 ")
   if [ "$mean" -eq 0 ]; then
     convert lumps.png -black-threshold "$l" -white-threshold "$h" -fill black -opaque white -threshold 1 mask_$mask.png
     ((mask++))
   fi
done
```

That gives us masks like this:

[image]

and this

[image]

we can see them all together if we do this

```
montage -tile 4x mask_* montage_masks.png
```

[image]

If we now apply each of the masks to the input image as the opacity and trim the resulting image, we will be left with the individual lumps of meat

```
seg=0
rm segment_*png 2> /dev/null
for f in mask_*png; do
   convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2VEJ.jpg $f -compose copy-opacity -composite -trim +repage segment_$seg.png
   ((seg++))
done
```

And they will look like this:

[image]

and this

[image]

Or, we can put them all together like this:

```
montage -background white -tile 4x segment_* montage_results.png
```

[image]

Cool question :-)

Answer (score 0):

With GIMP, you can do it the following way:

1. Use the `Magic Wand` (Select Contiguous Regions tool) and select your background;
2. Menu `Select` > `Invert` to get multiple selections;
3. Install the **script-fu** `export-selected-regions` below if you don't have it yet;
4. Menu `Select` > `Export Selected Regions`, your new images should be in the same folder as the original one.

If you're using `GIMP 2.10` on `mac`, put the script below in: `~/Library/Application\ Support/GIMP/2.10/scripts/export-selected-regions.scm`, check for the appropriate folder for other system.

```
;;; Non-interactively save all selected regions as separate files
(define (script-fu-export-selected-regions image drawable)
  ;; Start
  (gimp-image-undo-group-start image)

  ;; If there are selections
  (when (= 0 (car (gimp-selection-is-empty image)))
    (let ((number 1) (prefix "") (suffix ""))
      ;; Construct filename components
      (let* ((parts (strbreakup (car (gimp-image-get-filename image)) "."))
             (coextension (unbreakupstr (reverse (cdr (reverse parts))) "."))
             (extension (cadr parts)))
        (set! prefix (string-append coextension "_selection-" ))
        (set! suffix (string-append "." extension)))

      ;; Convert all selections to a single path
      (plug-in-sel2path RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable)

      ;; For each stroke in the path
      (let ((vectors (vector-ref (cadr (gimp-image-get-vectors image)) 0)))
        (for-each (lambda (stroke)
                    ;; Convert the stroke back into a selection
                    (let ((buffer (car (gimp-vectors-new image "buffer")))
                          (points (gimp-vectors-stroke-get-points vectors stroke)))
                      (gimp-image-insert-vectors image buffer 0 -1)
                      (apply gimp-vectors-stroke-new-from-points buffer points)
                      (gimp-vectors-to-selection buffer 2 TRUE FALSE 0 0)
                      (gimp-image-remove-vectors image buffer))

                    ;; Replace the selection with its bounding box
                    (apply (lambda (x0 y0 x1 y1)
                             (gimp-image-select-rectangle image 2 x0 y0 (- x1 x0) (- y1 y0)))
                             (cdr (gimp-selection-bounds image)))

                    ;; Extract and save the contents as a new file
                    (gimp-edit-copy drawable)
                    (let* ((image    (car (gimp-edit-paste-as-new)))
                           (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image)))
                           (filename ""))
                      (while (or (equal? "" filename) (file-exists? filename))
                        (let* ((digits (number->string number))
                               (zeros (substring "0000" (string-length digits))))
                          (set! filename (string-append prefix zeros digits suffix)))
                        (set! number (+ number 1)))
                      (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable filename filename)
                      (gimp-image-delete image)))
                  (vector->list (cadr (gimp-vectors-get-strokes vectors))))
        (gimp-image-remove-vectors image vectors))))

  ;; End
  (gimp-selection-none image)
  (gimp-image-undo-group-end image))

(script-fu-register "script-fu-export-selected-regions"
                    "Export Selected Regions"
                    "Export each selected region to a separate file."
                    "Andrew Kvalheim <Andrew@Kvalhe.im>"
                    "Andrew Kvalheim <Andrew@Kvalhe.im>"
                    "2012"
                    "RGB* GRAY* INDEXED*"
                    SF-IMAGE "Image" 0
                    SF-DRAWABLE "Drawable" 0)
(script-fu-menu-register "script-fu-export-selected-regions" "<Image>/Select")
```

Many thanks to Andrew Kvalheim for his [script-fu](https://gist.github.com/AndrewKvalheim/3702395).