# image recognition api and image count in an image

Tags: image

Is there any commercial or free image recognition api which can recognize images in an JPG/PNG and give all the imagecount of images in that image. Samples :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fbzsw0b3vdv988/537502-ravana-3.jpg?dl=0
The image count : 1

https://www.dropbox.com/s/me28f5sdwnkxy9e/testing.jpg?dl=0

The image count : 4

Regards

Kris

Comment: You could start here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/29758578/2836621

Comment: thanks @mark Setchell thanks so much will try and get back

Comment: @MarkSetchell I executed this command:  convert testing.jpg -threshold 98%     -morphology dilate octagon                               -define connected-components:area-threshold=800           -define connected-components:verbose=true               -connected-components 8 -auto-level PNG8:lumps.jpg , testing.jpg as attached in the dropbox url I am getting only one image this image is having 4 images in it. Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 592x745+0+0 295.5,372.0 441040 srgb(255,255,255) . Please help