# Split Image into parts ionic

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, css-grid

I want to divide the image into multiple parts dynamically based on dimensions in ionic 5.

let's say

- 3 piece
- 8 piece
- any number

I tried css tricks to make white color line on image but that hides the image portion behind.

I read this two blocks but helped me

[split base64 image into parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463416/split-base64-image-into-parts)

[Split image into parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888287/split-image-into-parts)

I want to show preview of selection.

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lBSQ.png)
Please help

Comment: wasn't my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to generate a component. I named it **img-tile-style**. then you put this codes in .html .css and .ts files.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-holder">
  <img [src]="imgSrc">
  <div class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:
(change the *img -> width & height* and the *.grid -> border color* for customization)

```
.image-holder {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  position: relative;
}

.image-holder img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}

.image-holder .grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px gray solid;
}
```

TypeScript:
(change the *border color* for customization)

```
export class ImgTileStyleComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() imgSrc: string;
  @Input() row: number;
  @Input() col: number;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.imgSrc, this.row, this.col);

    console.log('here');
    const grid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid')[0];
    console.log(grid);
    const row = '<div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-grow: 1;"></div>';
    const cell = '<div class="cell" style="flex-grow: 1; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px gray solid;"></div>';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.row; i++) {
      grid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', row);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.row; i++) {
      const el = document.getElementsByClassName('row')[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < this.col; j++) {
        el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cell);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

then in your project simply you use the tag: `<app-img-tile-style></app-img-tile-style>`

the attributes you have to set are:

> imgSrc imgSrc="./assets/images/defaultCompanyPic.png"
>
> row -> row="4"
>
> col -> col="3"

a complete example here:

```
<app-img-tile-style imgSrc="./assets/images/defaultCompanyPic.png" row="4" col="3"></app-img-tile-style>
```

I put this component on a repository on Github. Link: [img-tile-style](https://github.com/mahdizarei0614/img-tile-style).

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this with some styles...

HTML:

```
 <div class="image-holder">
    <img src="./assets/images/defaultCompanyPic.png">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-holder {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  position: relative;
}

.image-holder img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}

.image-holder .grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px gray solid;
}

.image-holder .grid .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.image-holder .grid .row .cell {
  flex-grow: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px gray solid;
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: It is useful but I want to set these pieces dyanamically

Comment: @cakePHP I will check it again today

Comment: @cakePHP are you using angular with ionic?

Comment: Yes, Using  ionic v5 with angular 8